# Stripe APi paymentIntent and sessions object

Tags: stripe-payments

I am having trouble finding out the difference between payment Intent and a session.

Assuming I a customer logs into a page and goes to `domain.com/register` how can I create session and check if customer has already visited page by using customer email address to get the customer object?

What are the difference between paymentIntent and session and how do they help? I see that session is created on `Checkout` but not when accepting one time payments.

Current I create a payment intent and it works find but my 'url' has no session

Answer (score 1):

### PaymentIntents

A PaymentIntent is an API object in Stripe's API that create encapsulates a lifecycle of a one-time payment.

You typically create your own form on your webpage when using PaymentIntents, create a PaymentIntent using the Stripe API, then confirm it using the cardElement from Stripe Elements (the frontend UI elements for collecting card details).

### Checkout

Checkout is a full page "hosted UI" that creates its own PaymentIntent and provides all the UI that a customer needs to enter their card details and takes a payment. It also supports many other payment methods automatically without you having to manually add support for each one.

So a CheckoutSession under the hood uses a Subscription or a PaymentIntent object, depending on whether it was used in `subscription` or `payment` mode.

Comment: so how can I create a one time link for one-time payment using `paymentIntent`? Or is that not possible?

Comment: what do you mean by "one time link"?